# Ranged query with Java Client API for Elasticseach 8.0+

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, range-query

I found some topics about ranged queries and Elasticsearch but these use the deprecated *High Level REST Client* interface. I also found a discussion on the elasticseach page which uses the new interface but for version `7.15.2`. The problem here is, that the query is built by a json-formatted string because the range query interface was not fully supported at this version.

Unfortunately, I can't find something helpful in the documentation, when it comes to the new *Java API Client* interface with version `8.0` or above.

I tried the following piece of code to get messages in multiple indices (`my-index-*`). I set the date and time format corresponding to the format used in the database. Next, I set the time boundaries with `from()` and `to()` and there exist data for the given period of time.

```
// ...
var client   = new ElasticsearchClient(...);
var response = client.search(
    s -> s.index("my-index-*")
          .query(q -> q.range(
              r -> r.field("recordtime")
                    .format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
                    .from("2020/01/01 00:00:00")
                    .to("2020/01/01 00:30:00"))),
    JsonNode.class);
```

When I execute the code above I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:281)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:147)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1526)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1543)
    at // the function including the line of code above.
```

These are my dependencies of my `build.gradle` corresponding to elasticsearch.

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation group: 'co.elastic.clients',         name: 'elasticsearch-java', version: '8.1.0'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind',   version: '2.13.0'
    // ...
}
```

So, what did I wrong? I prefer the way to use the builders API and not to create a json-string transform this to a `JsonData`-object and pass this to the `ElasticsearchClient` client.

---

I also tried now to query the search with a curl request and used the following lines:

```
curl -X GET -k -u elastic:$ESPASS "https://<es-server-url>:9200/my-index-*/_search"
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "recordtime": {
        "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss",
        "from": "2020/01/29 00:00:00",
        "to": "2020/01/29 00:30:00"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Here I get data from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the error.

I messed up with the date format. After correcting it I get results with the Java API.

The code of the question above works as intended. But in my real code I used a function to get the format of the timed field. Well, the format returned by the function was `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` but the correct format is (as written in the question) `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`. As you can see I swapped the days and the years.

Comment: Maybe you could specify the specific error you found so as to help any others that may run into this problem in the future?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).